# How do I set the z-index of a marker in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps, z-index, google-maps-markers

Can anyone explain the exact syntax used to set the z-index for a marker using the Google Maps API (Version 3)?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MarkerOptions):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    ....
    zIndex: 100 
});
```

Or via the [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Marker) setter:

```
marker.setZIndex(100);
```

Comment: does 100 move it closer to the user or farther away?

Comment: For anyone not familiar with z-index, it is a CSS property for height layering. It is not related to distance, and is not specific to Google Maps. I am using it to make markers of a particular type draw "on top" of other markers when multiple markers overlap.

Comment: @Phlip: the value (of 100) is relative, not absolute. Items with a value of 100 appear to be 'under' items with a higher value (which will appear to be closer to the user), but 'above' items with a lower value.

Answer (score 4):

zIndex is actually a relative term. For example, if you have two markers, marker1 and marker2, and the zIndex of marker1 is 100 and the zIndex of marker2 is 101: it means that marker2 is higher in the stack than marker1. As a result, marker2 will be on top or marker1, and in front of the user.

You can set the z-index using :

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map,
    zIndex: 100
});
```

If you have previously created a marker, then just use:

```
marker.setZIndex(101);
```